# Клавиши F1 - F12 на Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, клавиатура

У меня ноутбук. У него ОС Windows 10 и там для того чтобы нажать любой из <kbd>F1</kbd> - <kbd>F12</kbd> надо сначала нажать <kbd>Fn</kbd> а потом например <kbd>F12</kbd>. А если я иx нажимаю без <kbd>Fn</kbd> они делают стандартные функции - например <kbd>F1</kbd> отключает звук.
 **Как то можно поменять эти функции, чтобы например когда я нажал <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> отключился звук?**

Comment: В настройках BIOS не смотрели?

Comment: Нет. Сейчас посмотрю. А вы знайте именно какой раздел?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, можно. Найдите в BIOS пункт Action Keys Mode (Режим функциональных клавиш) и измените его значение.

Answer (score 2):

Нашёл ответ!

Вот [источник](https://toster.ru/q/218512).

Нажмите клавишу <kbd>F10</kbd> или <kbd>F2</kbd>, чтобы открыть окно установок BIOS. Окно можно открывать ещё из Настройки -> Обновление и безопасность -> Восстановление -> Особые варианты загрузки․

Перейдите в меню System Configuration (Конфигурация системы) с помощью клавиш со стрелками влево/вправо.
Окно настройки BIOS с выбранными параметрами System Configuration (Конфигурация системы) и Action Keys Mode (Режим функциональных клавиш)

Disabled (отключено): Требует нажатия и удерживания функциональной клавиши (fn) при одновременном нажатии одной из клавиш с <kbd>F1</kbd> по <kbd>F12</kbd> для использования функции, указанной на данной клавише.
К примеру, на некоторых компьютерах при Отключенном режиме функциональных клавиш нажатие f11 будет сворачивать и разворачивать окно веб-браузера, если оно открыто. При этом нажатие и удерживание сочетания клавиш <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> отключит звук.

Enabled (включено): Необходимо нажатие одной из клавиш с <kbd>F1</kbd> по <kbd>F12</kbd> для использования функции, указанной на данной клавише.

Нажмите клавишу <kbd>F10</kbd> или <kbd>F2</kbd>, чтобы сохранить изменения и перезагрузить компьютер.

Comment: Вы хоть укажите, о какой модели речь, не у всех же ноутбуков одинаковый BIOS. :)

Comment: @Yaant а откуда можно посмотреть это?

Comment: В смысле, Вы не знаете, какой у Вас ноутбук? Ну где-нибудь снизу обычно бывает табличка с названием модели.

Comment: Не я думал вы хотите модель BIOS. Модель ноутбука я конечно знаю.

Comment: Да нет, ноутбука, конечно. А то даже F10 далеко не у всех моделей вызывает BIOS. Может быть F2, например.